# Acessing object from object

Tags: php, oop, object

I'm starting with OOP in PHP and there is something I'd like to do. Let me show an example:

classes.php

```
<?php
    class a {
        public function a() {
            echo 'a';
        }
    }

    class b {
        public function calla() {
            $x->a();
        }
    }
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    include('classes.php');
    $x = new a();
    $d = new b();
    $d->calla();
?>
```

Is this possible? I know I can do something like:

```
class b {
        public function calla($object) {
            $object->a();
        }
    }
```

and

```
$d->calla($x);
```

but is the first example possible to do?

Comment: The sole purpose of `private` is to prevent that. Is `public` an option?

Comment: That's simply not going to work.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using ?

Comment: I'm sorry, i mistyped it. It would be a public function.

Comment: You need to pass the object in like your `public function calla($object) {` example. Or you could do bad things like declare `$x` globally from within `class b` but that's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to use `$x` as global variable? Syntax is the same, object or not:

```
class b {
    public function calla() {
        $GLOBALS['x']->a();
    }
}
```

... or:

```
class b {
    public function calla() {
        global $x;
        $x->a();
    }
}
```

Of course, it's a horrible design that injects hard to track dependencies and will probably lead to unexpected side effects and head-scratching.

Additionally, `a()` is a poor method name for class `a` because it's the PHP 4 syntax for constructors. If you run this code:

```
<?php

class a {
    public function a() {
        echo 'a';
    }
}

class b {
    public function calla() {
        $GLOBALS['x']->a();
    }
}

$x = new a();
$d = new b();
$d->calla();
```

... you'll see that `a()` runs twice. Guess why?

Comment: The global was what i wanted. Thank you. Didn't knew also about the naming of the method, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to ask but you're mixing up parameters visibility concept with object passing in class methods. So let's clean up...

In your classes.php file the method `calla()` of the class b as absolutely nothing to do with class `a`, unless `$x` itself is an instance of the class `a`.

In your index.php file you instantiate `$x` as class `a`, but it is a global variable, and the class `b` has no visibility on it. Moreover, your call to `$d->calla()` would return an error because you are accessing a private method from outside.

Your third example gets closer to the solution, passing the instance to the `calla()` method helps class `b` seing the instance of class `a`, I guess you want to edit your index.php file to:

```
<?php
include('class.php');
$x = new a();
$d = new b();
$d->calla($x);
?>
```

But this still won't work until you change the private methods to public ones.

Comment: I wrongly typed private, it was meant to be public. I understand that i can call **$d->calla()** and it would throw an error if the object $x didn't existed. The reason i asked is because i'm initiating and querying a mysql database through an class, and i want all other classes to be able to use that object($db in case) to query the database, without the need to create an object in each class or pass it through the function.

Comment: You can use global($x) inside your class methods to make $x visible in the inner scope then... :)